# Выпадающий список select + option, сделать как опцию в виджете элементора

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать выпадающий список select, что бы его можно было бы перемещать на страницу как виджет через элементор[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Написать свой виджет для элементор.

Comment: Это понятно, как там поля select + option задать

Comment: В каком смысле, как их задать? Можете чере [Repeater Control](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/editor-controls/control-repeater/), например, если это то о чем я подумал.

Comment: Да как вариант, только наверное он с селектами не работает

Comment: Да в каком смысле, не работает? Вы же селект будете выводить самостоятельно в `render()` методе виджета, где Вы можете сформировать что угодно. Посредством перебора массива из Repeater Control можете сформировать `options` для Вашего `select` элемента.

Comment: Спасибо большое